# From Datagridview to lable or last row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to get sum from datagridview to label or last row of datagridview
Please help me
Here is My code

```
public void total()
    {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in tbl_Purchase.Rows)
            {
                int n = item.Index;
                int tPrice=0;
                int tQuantity=0;
                int tAmount=0
                tPrice += (int.Parse(tbl_Purchase.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
                tQuantity += (int.Parse(tbl_Purchase.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
                tAmount += (int.Parse(tbl_Purchase.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value.ToString()));
                l_Price.Text = (Convert.ToString(tPrice));
                l_Quantity.Text = (Convert.ToString(tQuantity));
                l_Amount.Text = (Convert.ToString(tAmount));

            }

    }
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing with this code? One issue I can identify here is that you are declaring the integers inside the loop, so on every iteration the count is getting reset. move the declarations outside the loop

Comment: Move the variables out of the loop or else they can't be used for sums nor will they be accessible out of the loop!

Comment: When you can't figure out why a piece of code is not working the way you expect it to work use the debugger, put breakpoints and step through code to see exactly what happens and you'll identify the problem in no time. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A

Answer (score 1):

```
public void total()
    {
        var tPrice=0;
        var tQuantity=0;
        var tAmount=0
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in tbl_Purchase.Rows)
        {
            tPrice += (int.Parse(tbl_Purchase.Rows[item.Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
            tQuantity += (int.Parse(tbl_Purchase.Rows[item.Index].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
            tAmount += (int.Parse(tbl_Purchase.Rows[item.Index].Cells[5].Value.ToString()));    
        }
        l_Price.Text = (Convert.ToString(tPrice));
        l_Quantity.Text = (Convert.ToString(tQuantity));
        l_Amount.Text = (Convert.ToString(tAmount));
    }
```